# How to add to listbox through in-class method?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, oop, listbox

I have a product class and a store class within addproductto store method within store class. It's needed to add both of them to listbox1 and listbox2 respectively. Why the my code doesn't work?

Form1:

```
     static public List<Product> plist = new List<Product>();
     static public List<Store> slist = new List<Store>();

     slist.Add(new Store { Name = "Bargin Basin" });
        slist.Add(new Store { Name = "SuperMart" });

        plist.Add(new Product { Label = "Potatoes", Price = 3.60 });
        plist.Add(new Product { Label = "Fish", Price = 4.49 });

        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            string curItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            // Create New Product
            if (curItem == "Product")
            {
                FormP AP = new FormP();
                if (AP.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string _label = AP.textBox1.Text; double _price = Convert.ToDouble(AP.textBox2.Text);
                    var newproduct = new Product { Label = _label, Price = _price };                                                       
                    Store store = slist.Find(y => y == AP.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
                   // Store store = AP.comboBox1.SelectedItem as Store;                                    
                    AddProductsToStore(store, newproduct);
                    listBox2.EndUpdate();

                }
            }

  public static void AddProductsToStore(Store store, Product product)
        {
               store.AddProduct(product);
               MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Product {0} added to store {1}", product.Label, store.Name));      
        }
```

Classes:

```
   public class Store
    {
        //public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Rab> Rabs { get; set; }

        public Store()
        {
            Products = new List<Product>();
            Rabs = new List<Rab>();
        }

        public virtual void AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            product.StoresStockedIn.Add(this);
            Products.Add(product);   
        }
}
   public class Product
    {
       // public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Label { get; set; }
        public virtual double Price { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Store> StoresStockedIn { get; set; }

        public Product()
        {
            StoresStockedIn = new List<Store>();
        }
    }
```

NOTHING HAPPENED, CODE CONTINUE WORKS, BUT NOTHING CHANGED IN LISTBOX, ONLY PROGRAM CREATED ITEMS IN UP QUESTION CODE ARE SHOWN (((

Comment: Where are you even adding anything to any listbox??

Comment: @Rotem 
listBox1DataSource=slist
listBox2DataSource=plist

Comment: @Rotem how to start conversation with plist through in-class method?

Comment: AddProductsToStore(store, newproduct);

Comment: Please post the code that actually *adds the items to the lists.* That's what you need help with, right? Also, I see a call to `.EndUpdate()` but no call to `.BeginUpdate()`.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Yes, but in listbox 2 must be only item that stored in the stores from listbox 1. that's a code `private void ProductListUpdate()
 listBox2.Items.Clear();  foreach (Product p in plist) listBox2.Items.Add(p.Label.ToString()); } ` Also i have selectindexchanged void - `foreach (Product p in plist)
            {                
                if (Convert.ToString(p.StoresStockedIn) == listbox1item)
                {                    listBox2.Items.Add(p);
                }
            }`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, as it is hard to parse. Edit your original post and put your code in there. Please also clarify your original post; it's not clear what you're asking. What do you *expect* to happen, and what is *actually* happening?